# How to calculate number of bytes in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a code that looks as below:

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t distance[2];
    uint8_t reflectivity;      
}data_point;

typedef struct{
    uint8_t flag[2];
    uint8_t Azimuth[2];
    std::vector<data_point> points; // always size is 32 but not initialized whereas filled in run-time using emplace_back
}data_block;

typedef struct{
    uint8_t UDP[42];
    std::vector<data_block> data; // always size is 12 but not initialized whereas filled in run-time using emplace_back
    uint8_t time_stamp[4];
    uint8_t factory[2];
}data_packet;

static std::vector<data_packet> packets_from_current_frame;
```

Assuming `packets_from_current_frame.size() = 26`, How can I calculate the number of bytes in `packets_from_current_frame`?

My solution on paper:

1 `data_packet` (assuming 32 `points` and 12 `data`) will have `42+ (12*(2+2+32(3))) + 4 + 2 = 1248`. Hence, the end address is `_begin + sizeof(uint8_t) * 26 * 1248` (`_begin` is the start address of the memory buffer).

With this calculation I always loose some data. Number of bytes that is lost depends on `packets_from_current_frame.size()`. What is wrong with the calculation?

Comment: *data_packet (assuming 32 points and 12 data) will have 42+ (12*(2+2+32(3))) + 4 + 2 = 1248* -- And there is your possible flaw -- the calculation.  You didn't take into account any fields used for padding within the struct.  The number of bytes that `data_packet` takes up is `sizeof(data_packet)`, not some calculation you came up with.

Comment: what do you mean with "always loose some data" ? number of bytes in the vector is `sizeof(data_packet)` * number of elements

Comment: Thank you both of you. Is it possible to calculate in run-time?

Comment: Note: The vector does not store its data locally. The  vector contains pointers to the actual data so if you are simply copying the byte info from these structures that will fail. In C++ an objects state is controlled via the constructor/destructor you can **NOT** just copy the raw data of a vector and place in another vector object and expect it to work. What are you actually trying to do here that you need the byte offset of things.

Comment: I am using boost buffer to send this data to a client. I need to know the size of the data (start address of the serialized data is known).

Comment: Then as Martin said _this solution cannot work_. You must not treat a `data_packet` as a serialisable block of bytes. You must not serialise a vector like that. You should write a proper serialiser... Besides, if the vectors "always have 32/12 elements" (even if it takes you a while to build up to it) why not just have arrays? Then you _can_ treat them as blocks of bytes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
int main() {
    static std::vector<data_packet> packets_from_current_frame;

    std::cout << "sizeof data_point  = " << (sizeof(data_point)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof data_block  = " << (sizeof(data_block)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof data_packet = " << (sizeof(data_packet)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof data_point  = 3
sizeof data_block  = 32
sizeof data_packet = 80
```

From this it is clear why your calculation fails.

You have forgotten to take into account things like the vector itself, fields after the vector and padding.

The correct way to calculate it is:

```
packets_from_current_frame.size() * (sizeof(data_packet) + data.size() * (sizeof(data_block) + points.size() * sizeof(data_point)))
```

Note: This amount of bytes are not stored in one consecutive memory block so don't try any direct memcpy.

The individual vector has consecutive data. If you want to know the address of the data held by a vector, use vector::data()